# File name in numpy.savetxt

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to ask how to allow for the file name in numpy.savetxt to include the value of a parameter of a for cycle containing the numpy.savetxt operation.

For example, what would be the correct syntax for 'k.txt' in the following example?

```
for k in range(10):
    x=range(k)
    y=range(k)
    np.savetxt('k.txt',np.transpose([x,y]))
```

Comment: `"k{:d}.txt".format(k)`?

Comment: ... or `f'k{k}.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below:

```
import numpy as np
for k in range(10):
    x=range(k)
    y=range(k)
    np.savetxt(f'{k}.txt',np.transpose([x,y]))
```